# Function coming back undefined in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

```
function people (name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}

var rob = new people("robert jr", 41);
var sam = new people("sam davies", 25);

function isOlderThan(age) {
  if(rob.age > sam.age) 
    return true;
  else return false;
}
```

I tried running it with this sam.isOlderThan(rob);

But it's not working. I'm kinda new to this, any help?

Comment: You're not using the `age` argument anywhere. Your function simply checks if `rob` is older than `sam`, every single time. Nor is `isOlderThan` a method of `sam`.

Comment: `people` has no `.isOlderThan()` method. Why do you think `sam.isOlderThan(rob)` should work? (and constructor functions, functions that will be used with the `new` keyword, should start with a capital letter)

Comment: You still have to call the function. When I use `isOlderThan()`, i get back 'true', since rob is older than sam.

Comment: HI there, we generally need a little more info than 'it's not working' to help. What's the error, at what line does it occur etc. It makes it easier for us to hep you with more information!

Answer (score 2):

```js
//  If you want to be able to call this as sam.isOlderThan()
//  you need to use a prototype to add that function to the persons
//  so they all have that function bound to them.
function person (name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}
person.prototype.isOlderThan = function( other_person ) {
  return this.age > other_person.age;
};
var rob = new person("robert jr", 41);
var sam = new person("sam davies", 25);

console.log( sam.isOlderThan( rob ) );
console.log( rob.isOlderThan( sam ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `isOlderThan` is not defined on people.

You could use a [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) on people if you want to call it like `sam.isOlderThan(rob);`

```js
function People(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}

var rob = new People("robert jr", 41);
var sam = new People("sam davies", 25);

People.prototype.isOlderThan = function(p) {
  return this.age > p.age;
};

console.log(sam.isOlderThan(rob));
console.log(rob.isOlderThan(sam));
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome to StackOverflow.
Assuming you mean to use the people function to define a type of class, and isOlderThan as a type of function of that class - notice the changes.

1. Constuctor functions (such as People) are commonly written with a leading Capital letter
2. For linking isOlderThan to an existing class - you should use the prototype syntax as shown below.
3. Inside the isOlderThan function we make a reference to `this` - which indicates the current object for which the isOlderThan than function was called.

Now we can call the isOlderThan function for each People object we create.

```js
function People(name, age) 
{
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}

var rob = new People("robert jr", 41);
var sam = new People("sam davies", 25);


People.prototype.isOlderThan = function(age) {
    if (this.age > age) 
        return true;
     else return false;
}

console.log(sam.isOlderThan(50))
console.log(rob.isOlderThan(sam.age))
```

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `sam.isOlderThan` because there is no `isOlderThan` function defined in `people` function ( correlate with class of other languages ).

`isOlderThan` is defined in global scope.

So, you can run it as `isOlderThan()` or `window.isOlderThan()` ( provided you are inside browser )

There's no need to pass `age`, `rob` or `sam` as they are defined in global scope and is available inside `isOlderThan` function.

Answer (score 0):

See if this Fiddle helps:

```
function Person(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}

var rob = new Person("robert jr", 41);
var sam = new Person("sam davies", 25);

function isOlderThan(rob, sam) {
  if (rob.age > sam.age) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

console.log(`Rob is older than Sam: ${isOlderThan(rob, sam)}`);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ao2ucrmq/1/